# Pandas: How to delete string with some value

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
              subdomain search_engine search_term  
0                    vk.com          None        None  
1                    vk.com          None        None  
2              facebook.com          None        None  
3                    vk.com          None        None  
4                    vk.com          None        vkontakte
```

I need to get `4                    vk.com          None        vkontakte`

I try

```
df[~df.search_term.str == r"None"]
```

But it returns `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'StringMethods'`

Comment: does `df[df['search_term'].notnull()]` work?

Comment: @EdChum None - it's string. And when I use your example it doesn't delete anything

Comment: How about `df[df['search_term']!= "None"]`

Comment: @EdChum it returns all dataframe

Comment: Then the cell element is not what you think it is can you show what `df['search_term'].iloc[0]` and `type(df['search_term'].iloc[0])` returns

Comment: @EdChum `df['search_term'].iloc[0]` return `None`, `type(df['search_term'].iloc[0])` return `<type 'str'>`

Comment: What does `len(df['search_term'].iloc[0])` show? You may have unprintable or spaces in the string

Comment: @EdChum `len(df['search_term'].iloc[0])` return `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
In[75]:df[df.search_term.str.strip()!='None']
Out[75]: 
  subdomain search_engine search_term
4    vk.com          None   vkontakte
```

or will this work:

```
df[~df.search_term.str.match('None')]
```

Comment: I think I have some problem with my `csv` file. Nothing works

Comment: It didn't help. I have replaced this string to `0`, but it didn't work too

Comment: try the solution with `str.match`.

Comment: Can you say, why did it happen? `df[~df.search_term.str.match('None')]` this not works but `df = df[~df.search_term.str.match('None')]` works?

Comment: what was the output when you ran the first statement without assigning it to df.

Comment: then I don't know because when you run the first statement it should show the expected output, maybe its a bug report it.If you find the reason then post it.